# Add hyperlink to an image via cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

is there a way to add a hyperlink, provided from a cell, to an image?

I tried the following VBA code:

```
Sub Storage_Test_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=storage_image, Address:=Worksheets("Links").Range("B8:B8").Value
End Sub
```

But with this piece of code, the link is persistent. In other words, if I change the cell value, the link from the image is not affected.

Thanks,
Tro

Comment: Based on your code, you will have to click the button when you change the value of B8 to update the link. If you want it to automatically attach the link to the image upon changing B8, you need Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter something like this in a ***Module***

```
Sub Add_HLink(ws As Worksheet, picture_name As String)
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Link")
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture And shp.Name = picture_name Then
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add shp, sh.Range("B8").Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then in your ***Link Sheet***:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, [B8]) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> use the sub here, assuming Picture named "Picture 1" is in Sheet2
        Add_HLink Sheet2, "Picture 1" '~~> change the arguments to suit
    End If
continue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume continue
End Sub
```

Is this what you're trying? HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=storage_image, Address:=Worksheets("Links").Range("B8:B8").Value
End Sub
```

dont assign the macro to the image, because you can't click on the image (as it's a hyperlink!), if you right click your image with your original code after updating your link, im sure that selects it and your macro will run, however the above changes should mean everytime you make a selection on your sheet, your links will update